# Should I create a new storage account specifically to store Azure Diagnostics data?

Tags: windows, azure, azure-storage, azure-diagnostics

I currently have a single "storage account" on Windows Azure for application data. Note that this storage account is tied to the CDN. I want to start collecting diagnostic data and persisting it to a storage account. Should I set-up a new storage account for this or is it ok to use the existing account?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use a new account.  Definitely recommended that you use a different account in fact (I build a product that monitors Windows Azure diagnostics).  Remember that there is an overall Tx limit to your storage account (5000 tx/sec).  You do not want diagnostics impacting the performance of your storage account. There are other reasons as well:  for instance, if you outsource your monitoring it is nice to be able to give the entire account over for inspection without exposing your application data.  Deletion of data and account rolling is much easier as well (when trimming old data).

I think [David](http://www.davidaiken.com/2011/11/15/ten-basic-troubleshooting-tips-for-windows-azure/) recommends it too (see #1).  That, by itself is reason enough.  ;)

Comment: That's reason enough to create a separate storage account. Thx.

Comment: I did not know about the 5000 tx/sec cap on storage account. Do you have any reference where it is documented? Thanks!

Comment: @JoannesVermorel  Not sure where this is documented.  I know that Brad Calder has said it on numerous occasions.

Comment: 5000 tx/sec cap per storage account is documented here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2010/05/10/windows-azure-storage-abstractions-and-their-scalability-targets.aspx

Answer (score -2):

I would use the existing account. I personally don't see a reason to have diagnostics data in separate account. Plus you only have (be default) only 5 storage accounts per subscription.

There is no reason to worry about the CDN connection. CDN only applies to a BLOB storage, and is only in "charge" when a resource is requested though the CDN url.

Comment: Yeah, this is where I was leaning. Does anyone have a reason as to why I shouldn't store the diagnostics data in the same account as the application data?

Comment: I disagree. As dunnry stated above, a storage account has a transaction rate limit. Storage accounts cost nothing to create. You can easily contact customer support and have more storage accounts added. Go back and read dunnry's answer. Let's say you subscribe to a scaling service from Cumulux or Paraleap, for example. You need to give them a key to your storage account, so they can analyze your metrics. You really want to expose your app's core data too? I think not. And just wait til you exceed your storage acct's limit because of too much diagnostics. This decision is a no-brainer.